# Steps involved in any file read/write operation in linux

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

Would like to request your help in understanding all the steps involved in file operations (read/write) starting from user space to VFS to respective file system to respective driver and then getting data from hardware.

It would be great if someone can explain with examples.

Thanks,
rao.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite broad topic, as it goes from the very top to the very bottom of the system. Take a look at [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6237) explaining the anatomy of the read/write system calls and [this document](http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html) about unix system calls.